# Why am I getting 'req.body undefined' when trying to push a new nested array in an array through update request in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Actually I am trying to push a new nested array inside an array through **update** request for an API. I am using all necessary middleware such as `app.use(express.json())` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));` and also the `multipart/form-data` in the postman header but still I am getting the **`req.body`**  undefined.

Below is the **Update request** code

```
const Update =async (req,res)=>{
    const _id = req.params.id
    const {Episodes} = req.body

    try{
        const UpdatedPodcast = await Podcasts.updateOne({
            _id
        },
        {
            $push:{
                Episodes:[{
                    Episodes
                }]
        }
        },
        {
            upsert:true,
            new:true
        }
        )
        console.log(Episodes)
        // console.log(data)
        res.send(UpdatedPodcast)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            message:"Error in updating the data"
        })
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Below is the **schema** for API data

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const PodcastSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        CategoryName:String,
        Episodes:[
            {
                EpisodeNo:Number,
                EpisodeName:String,
                EpisodeDescription:String,
                imageurl:String
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        timestamps:true
    })

module.exports = mongoose.model('PodcastSchema',PodcastSchema)
```

Below is the screenshot of POSTMAN request

[image]

I have tried to access the Episodes array through different method but still getting req.body undefined. Can someone help me to find solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have included the `express.json()` middleware before your route handlers and before your route definition. Also, ensure that you are sending the request with the correct `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`. In Postman, make sure to select "raw" and "JSON (application/json)" options for the request body.

Comment: Actually, I am uploading images also that's why in Postman I am using form and for that i am adding the multipart/data-form in the header

Answer (score 0):

When looking on your screenshot, I notice that there a no field representing the `Episodes` field which is the array your looking for.

So basically, it's normal that your
`const {Episodes} = req.body`give your null.

Note that it's not the req.body null, but the `{Episodes}` field which is absent.

What I suggest:

- Add some endpoint to update the `Episodes` field of a podcast. These endpoint can be:

```js
// 1. this allow you to add new add to your Episodes field.
// Note: When posting a multi-format data like in your screenshot to this route, thing should go ok
/podcast/[ID]/new-episode


// 2. remove an episode from a podcast

/podcast/[ID]/remove-episode/[IndexOfTheEpidode]


//3. Remove the first episode of a podcast
/podcast/[ID]/remove-first

//3. Remove the last episode of a podcast
/podcast/[ID]/remove-last

// 4. Update an episode of a podcast 
/podcast/[ID]/update-episode/[IndexOfTheEpidode]
```

2. About your controller

I think, the different controller for the above route are just dealing with array stuffs.

3. About the Data you send to your API

In my sample, `[ID]` is the podcast id and `[IndexOfTheEpidode]` is the index of the target episode in your podcast's episodes array.

Now you can use approximatively what is in your screen.

Comment: Feel free to add comment if need to allow me ajust my answer